# I renamed form and forgot to save visual studio C# - How do I fix this error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, save, load, windows-forms-designer

I renamed a form and forgot to save my Visual Studio Project. Now I am getting this error:
`The file does not support code parsing or generation because it is not contained within a project that supports code.`

I can still see the original form name and when I double click the specific form this is the error I get:
`the item does not exist it may have been moved, renamed, or deleted`

How do I fix my problem? I just want access to the form I renamed and I am guessing the project is not reading for the new one (but unsaved) and is searching for the original which does not exist anymore.

Comment: You can edit the csproj file of your project and fix the mistake in there. You can do it in notepad outside of Visual Studio, or you can do it inside Visual Studio if you unload the project.

Comment: So every instance of the new form I see I rename to the old one? Or the other way around?

Comment: Possible solution... Select your project in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer panel, then click the 'Show All Files' icon from the Solution Explorer menu at the top of the panel. In your Solution Explorer tree, find your files in question, Select the old filename, Right Click and select Exclude From Project. For the new file name, select it from your Solution Explorer and select Include In Project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @quaabaam! I figured it out from @KingOfArrows 's solution. I will mark this question as answered with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem from @KingOfArrows 's comment, but I may as well post it here. I was able to solve the issue by editing every instance of the old version in the .csproj file by:

1. Right clicking on the project and selecting `unload project` in the solution viewer
2. Right clicking the project and clicking `edit project file` (if it hadn't already appeared automatically), and then changing every reference of the old name to the new name in the text
3. I closed out of the entire visual studio application and when I reopened it, I right clicked again the project in the solution viewer and clicked `reload project`, causing everything to work properly.

I hope this helps anyone if they run into the same issue.

Comment: @IDoNotKnowHowToProgram, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.